# After Effects: Return value if variable equals part of a set of numbers

Tags: expression, after-effects

I'm writing an AE Expression that will spit out a number based on an Effect's keyframed value on the same layer. That is, if it's 1, value is 100, if it's 2, value is 101, if it's 3, 99, etc. Here's what I've got working:

```
x = effect("Mouth")("Slider");

if (x == 7 || x == 11 || x == 16) {
103
} else if (x == 6 || x == 10 || x == 15 || x == 25 || x == 26){
102
} else if (x == 5 || x == 9 || x == 12 || x == 14 || x == 19 || x == 24 || x == 27 || x == 28){
101
} else {
100
}
```

Surely there is a more elegant way to do this? I've tried writing it

```
if (x == 7 || 11 || 16)
```

but telling After Effects X absolutely equals "this" OR "that" just makes it assume it also equals "everything". Argh.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little weird (arguably elegant?), but if you're just looking for something more compact, you could do:

```
x = effect("Mouth")("Slider");

if (",7,11,16,".indexOf(","+x+",") != -1) {
 103
} else if (",6,10,15,25,26,".indexOf(","+x+",") != -1) {
 102
} else if (",5,9,12,14,19,24,27,28,".indexOf(","+x+",") != -1) {
 101
} else {
 100
}
```

but don't forget the commas at both ends!

I thought about using ECMA's array.indexOf(x), but it is not supported in AE's JS expressions. [edit: mistakedly wrote 'offsetOf']

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other approaches you could use. You can compress this code more, but I left it spread out for readability.

For shorter lists you can use a switch/case and have multiple options execute the same code. Like so:

```
thingToTest = effect("Mouth")("Slider");

switch (thingToTest) {
    case 7:
    case 11:
    case 16:
        result = 103;
        break;
    case 6:
    case 10:
    case 15:
    case 25:
    case 26:
        result = 102;
        break;
    case 5:
    case 9:
    case 12:
    case 14:
    case 19:
    case 24:
    case 27:
    case 28:
        result = 101;
        break; 
    default:
        result = 100;
        break;
}
```

The problem is that if you have a lot of possible outcomes to check for, that could become quite unwieldy. In which case, I'd make the values for each outcome case be an array and loop through them.

```
thingToTest = effect("Mouth")("Slider");

mySet1 = [7, 11, 16];
mySet2 = [6, 10, 15, 25, 26];
mySet3 = [5, 9, 12, 14, 19, 24, 27, 28];

result = 100; // Default

foundIt = 0;

for (i = 0; i < mySet1.length; i++) {
    if (mySet1[i] == thingToTest) {
        result = 103;
        foundIt = 1;
        break;
    }
}

if(foundIt) {
    for (i = 0; i < mySet2.length; i++) {
        if (mySet2[i] == thingToTest) {
            result = 102;
            foundIt = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(foundIt) {
    for (i = 0; i < mySet3.length; i++) {
        if (mySet3[i] == thingToTest) {
            result = 101;
            foundIt = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

result;
```

Putting the successive groups in a conditional statement marginally improves performance by not iterating through those arrays if a match has already been found. For efficiency, it would make sense to test against the contents of your longest list of numbers first, because it's more likely to contain the match.

These solutions may not be as compact but are definitely scaleable.